# Find Delta for given epsilon

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)$ =
\begin{cases}
 \frac { 2x^4 - 5x^2y^2 + y^5 }{(x^2 + y^2)^2 } &\text{ whenever $(x,y)$ is not $(0,0)$ } \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y)$ = $(0,0)$ }
\end{cases}

find $\delta$ > $0$ such that, | $f(x,y)$-$f(0,0)$ | < $0.01$ whenever, 
 $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} <\delta $

I tried to group the numerator in the function but couldn't do it successfully. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \ne 0$ we have $f(x,0)=2$.

Consequence: no such $ \delta$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to polar.

$\frac{2r^4\cos^4 \theta - 5r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta + r^5\sin^5\theta}{r^4}\\
2\cos^4 \theta - 5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta + r\sin^5\theta$

It would appear that the limit does not exist.